# ServletFilter called, but ignored on Jetty

Tags: jetty, servlet-filters

I cannot get this very basic ServletFilter run on Jetty (target is 6.1.25, but I also tried 8.1.10).

I can see in the log, that the filter is actually called and the header values are set without error, but they do not appear on the client side, so the values are ignored or overwritten.

Even more odd, when GzipFilter is set additionally, the filter works and header values become visible at the client (for compressed requests only).

Can somebody reproduce this, or tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is the Filter:

```
public class AppCacheFilter implements Filter{

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    System.out.println("response: " + httpResponse);
    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=2,public");
    httpResponse.setHeader("X-Powered-By", "X-Power");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Warning", "Whatever");
    System.out.println("response: " + httpResponse);

}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}
public void destroy() {}
}
```

and this is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>AppCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <display-name>AppCache Filter</display-name>
    <filter-class>de.socsoc.filter.AppCacheFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AppCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `httpResponse.setHeader()` calls before `chain.doFilter(request, response)`, like this:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

System.out.println("response: " + httpResponse);
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=2,public");
httpResponse.setHeader("X-Powered-By", "X-Power");
httpResponse.setHeader("Warning", "Whatever");
System.out.println("response: " + httpResponse);

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

as in general you should not add headers, if you already had written something to the response. Some servers will give you "Response already committed" error message, some may silently ignore your added headers. By moving this in front of the `chain.doFilter()` you ensure that no content has been written to response and headers can be safely set.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately changing headers before chain.doFilter() does not change the behavior.

Comment: @schulzki So maybe it is problem with Jetty. I've tested it on two containers WebSphere App Server 8.5.5.1 and WebSphere Liberty Core 8.5.5.1 and works fine on both. Tested if headers are set via FireBug.

Comment: Yes, it is a jetty problem. Considering Gas' answer + using jetty 8.1.15 + removing "cache-control" settings for the default servlet finally fixed it. Note, that this does not work on Jetty 6.x! The "cache-control" header is overwritten by the default servlet no matter if cache-control is configured or not!